# adding multiple date time fields in crystal reports 8

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I am printing Attendance register in crystal reports 8 and finding difficulty in Calculating Total Working Hours for the month of employees...

Fields coming from database are :

```
Days Of The Week (Sun,Mon...) its Data Type is Varchar.
Time In (6:50,6:55...) its Data Type is Date Time.
Time Out (4:00, 4:30...) its Data Type is also Date Time.
Working Hours (9:10, 9:35...) its Data Type is also Date Time.
```

Working hours are basically the total time that employee spent on a particular date.

Now the problem i am facing is that i want to get Total Working hours of the month that an employee spent on job and for that i want to total each day Working hours of the month but i can't sum because its not allowing to to sum as its data type is date time while we can sum only numbers in crystal reports formula.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have any field that give you the full date(example 8/25/2014) rather that week day?

Comment: one solution can be... convert the hours and minutes to seconds (basically number format) then add those and reconvert into hours and minutes.